# Through/via vs. By

Tags: word-choice, difference

Which one is a better choice?

> In my view, specialist betrays society **by** wounding his own ego.

Or

> In my view, specialist betrays society **through/via** wounding his own ego.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is better. The main difference between these two prepositions is, "by" is mostly used when referring to a means of something while "through" is used in relation to a process. In this case the sentence refers to the *means of something*, so it is more suited.

Answer (score 1):

**Via** is definitely inappropriate; it means *by way of* in the context of making a journey.

I'm not quite sure what your sentence means, but I think **by** feels more idiomatic than **through.**